# Intercambiar de nodos lista simplemente enlazada en C (swap de nodos)

Tags: c, punteros, nodos

Necesito hacer ***SWAP*** entre nodos de una lista simplemente enlazada  pero se pierden las uniones de punteros en el camino, supongo que estoy metiéndome en un bucle o estoy asignando mal punteros.

Aquí dejo mi intento de ***swap***: *(**Nota**: Los índices de la lista parten desde 1).*

Estructura que utilizo para la lista enlazada:

```
typedef struct Lista{
  int dato;
  int dato2;
  struct Lista * sig;
}Lista;
```

Función que retorna el largo de una lista enlazada:

```
int largoL(Lista ** cabeza){
    if (*cabeza != NULL){
        int contador = 0;
        Lista * aux = *cabeza;
        while( aux != NULL){
            contador +=1;
            aux = aux->sig;
        }
        return contador;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }   
}
```

Función rtrNodo entrega el puntero de un nodo en una lista. Retorna un nodo dada una posición.

```
Lista * rtrNodo(Lista ** cabeza, int posicion){
    if (posicion < largoL(cabeza) +1){
        int contador = 1;
        Lista * aux = *cabeza;
        while( contador < posicion){
            contador +=1;
            aux = aux->sig;
        }
        return aux;
    }else{
        printf("No existe la poscion \n");
        return NULL;
    }
}

void swapnodosL(Lista ** cabeza, int indice1, int indice2){
    if (*cabeza != NULL){
        int largo = largoL(cabeza);
        //Utilizaremos este temporal para intercambiar nodos.           
        if (indice1 <= largo && indice2 <= largo){
            //Evitar doble trabajo más adelante
            Lista * pi1 = rtrNodo(cabeza,indice1);
            Lista * pi2 = rtrNodo(cabeza,indice2);

            Lista * pSi1 = pi1->sig;
            Lista * pSi2 = pi2->sig;

            if (indice1 == 1 || indice2 == 1){
                if (indice1 == 1){
                    Lista * pAi2 = rtrNodo(cabeza,indice2-1);
                    pAi2->sig = pi1;
                    pi1->sig  = pSi2;

                    pi1  = pi2;
                    pi2->sig  = pSi1;

                //Caso indice2 = 1
                }else{
                    Lista * pAi1 = rtrNodo(cabeza,indice1-1);

                    *cabeza  = pi1;
                    (*cabeza)->sig  = pSi2;

                    pAi1->sig = pi2;
                    pi2->sig  = pSi1;                   
                }
            //Caso ninguno es cabeza    
            }else{
                Lista * pAi1 = rtrNodo(cabeza,indice1-1);
                Lista * pAi2 = rtrNodo(cabeza,indice2-1);
                pAi2->sig = pi1;
                pi1->sig  = pSi2;
                pAi1->sig = pi2;
                pi2->sig  = pSi1;                   
            }
        }
    }else{
        printf("La lista es nula o indices fuera de rango, no se ha logrado el swap\n");
    }
```

}

Comment: Que es largoL y cual es la estructura de Lista?

Comment: Me disculpo, ahí modifique la pregunta para completar con la estructura y la función largoL

Comment: Lista * pAi2 = rtrNodo(cabeza,indice2-1);
                    pAi2->sig = pi1;
                    pi1->sig  = pSi2; si indice2 =1 entonces te traes el indice 1 y a este le asignas next a el mismo luego lo chancas. Eso está medio raro

Comment: Ahora, me pregunto ¿porque no solamente intercambia los datos y te olvidas de los punteros?

Comment: Me lo propuse en su minuto, pero necesito este conocimiento a pesar que en estos momentos se pueda resolver de forma mas sencilla.

Answer (score 0):

Trata con este seudo codigo:

```
   Swap(**cabecera,i1,i2){

           Si i1==i2 salir
             Si i1==0 || i2==0 salir


                In1=i1<i2? i1 : i2; // el menor indice
                In2=i1==in1 ? i2 : i1; // el mayor indice
                in0=in1 - 1; // indice devla lista anterior

                  Si in0 == 0 // no existe lista anterior
                      // swap con la cabecera
                        N1=*cabecera // nodo 1
                       N2=obtenerNodo(in2) // nodo2
                       T0 = N2->SIG // temp del nodo 2 siguiente
                         N2->SIG =N1->sig 
                        N1->sig=T0
                         *cabecera= N2; // lcabecera ahora es N2

                  In0 != 0 // Existe un nodo anterior
                       N1=obtenerNodo(in1)
                       N2=obtenerNodo(in2)
                       T0=N2->sig
                       N0=obtenerNodo(in0) // nodo anterior al primero
                      N0->SIG = N2 
                      N2->sig = N1
                      N1->SIG = t0
```